# Как можно реализовать запрос в Stream Analitycs Job на Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure

Доброго времени суток. Ситуация следующая, на удалённом объекте имеются датчики которые отсылают показатели в IoT HUB на платформе Microsoft Azure при помощи протокола MQTT в виде JSON. Далее есть Stream Analytics Job, который парсит JSON и передаёт её в SQL Database и дальше происходит визуализация данных.

Само дело вот в чём, есть два вида отправки JSON один с потоковыми значениями в массиве при аварийной ситуации на удалённом объекте, а другой отсылает раз в 30 минут одиночный показатель при нормальном состоянии.

Имеется следующий запрос в Stream Analytics, для парса JSON, который принимает потоковый ввод массива, но игнорирует ввод одиночного показателя без массива:

```
    SELECT
dateadd(ms, flat.arrayindex * input.LeakSampl,
dateadd(second, cast(substring(input.DT, 16, 2) as bigint),
dateadd(minute, cast(SUBSTRING(input.DT, 13, 2) as bigint), 
dateadd(hour, cast(SUBSTRING(input.DT, 10, 2)as bigint), 
dateadd(day, cast(SUBSTRING(input.DT, 1, 2)as bigint) -1, 
dateadd(month, cast(SUBSTRING(input.DT, 4, 2)as bigint) - 1, 
dateadd(year, cast(SUBSTRING(input.DT, 7, 2)as bigint), 
cast('2000-01-01T00:00:00' as datetime)))))))) as DT, 
cast(input.EventEnqueuedUtcTime as datetime) as EventEnqueuedUtcTime,
cast(input.EventProcessedUtcTime as datetime) as EventProcessedUtcTime,     
input.IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId as object_name,
GetArrayElement(input.[in],0) as in0a,
GetArrayElement(input.[in],1) as in0b,
GetArrayElement(input.[in],2) as in0c, 
GetArrayElement(input.in1,0)  as in1a,
GetArrayElement(input.in1,1)  as in1b,
GetArrayElement(input.in1,2)  as in1c,
GetArrayElement(input.out1,0) as out1a,
GetArrayElement(input.out1,1) as out1b,
GetArrayElement(input.out1,2) as out1c,
GetArrayElement(input.out2,0) as out2a,
GetArrayElement(input.out2,1) as out2b,
GetArrayElement(input.out2,2) as out2c,
GetArrayElement(input.out3,0) as out3a,
GetArrayElement(input.out3,1) as out3b,
GetArrayElement(input.out3,2) as out3c,
flat.ArrayValue as Leak,
input.leakmin,
input.leakmax
INTO
elmontpower
FROM
elmoniothub as input
cross apply getarrayelements(input.LeakArr) as flat;
```

Пример JSON:
1. Для поточного ввода:

```
    {
"DT":"03.01.17 15:15:15",
"in":[1,0,0],
"in1":[1,1,0],
"out1":[0,1,1],
"out2":[1,1,0],
"out3":[1,0,0],
"leakmin":350,
"leakmax":350,
"LeakSampl":3800,
"LeakArr":[150,34,56,250,12]
}
```

2.Для ввода без потоковых данных:

```
    {
"DT":"03.01.17 15:15:15",
"in":[1,0,0],
"in1":[1,1,0],
"out1":[0,1,1],
"out2":[1,1,0],
"out3":[1,0,0],
"Leak":350,
"leakmin":350,
"leakmax":350,
}
```

Вопрос вот в чём, как реализовать запрос, чтобы когда приходили одиночные данные для Leak, они обрабатывались и попадали в базу данных и также принимались массивы данных для Leak?

Comment: _Имеется следующий запрос в Stream Analytics, для парса JSON, который принимает потоковый ввод массива, но игнорирует ввод одиночного показателя без массива:_  а как этот запрос принимает параметры? покажите всю картину

Comment: неплохо бы пару комментариев к коду тоже

Comment: @Anatol JSON отправляется устройством в сторону stream analytics и запрос парсит JSON  и данные раскидывает по табличке.